# External devices interfering with GPS

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I recently bought a FM transmitter to broadcast my music to my car's speakers. However, I discovered that while the transmitter was plugged into my phone I couldn't get a GPS signal.

I imagine that the reason for this is that the phone uses headphone devices as an antenna when they are plugged in. This transmitter plugs into the headphone jack. Unfortunately though, this transmitter does not make a good antenna.

Question: Is there a way for me to force my Samsung Galaxy SII (Epic Touch 4g) not to use that as an antenna?

Comment: Samsung denies the antenna theory. I guess the device is simply interfering.

Comment: II guess the Samsung employee denying that didn't know what he was talking about. Phones offering an FM radio to my knowledge *all* use the headset cable as antenna. You should be able to verify that: turn on the radio, and try using the integrated speakers (by unplugging your headset cable). See whether it continues "playing", and if the quality stays the same. I'm pretty sure the speaker will turn on, but the station will be gone – or at least the quality will drop markably due to "antenna loss". If so, ask "Samsung" for the reason :)

Comment: About FM radio you are no doubt correct. My question is about GPS, which doesn't need anything plugged into the headphone jack. I was wondering if it switches over to using the headphones as the preferred antenna.

Comment: Shouldn't do so for GPS (AFAIK GPS always uses its own antenna), but I'm not sure whether some software-bug could trigger exactly that. Afraid not much we can do; as indicated, I'd confront Samsung with that. I'd consider it a serious limitation they have to act on, at least when the device is under warranty, and should either repair or replace the device at no cost for you.